# Modify Spark Dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a spark dataframe to which i need to make some change

Input dataframe :

```html
+-----+-----+----------+
| name|Index| Value    | 
+-----+-----+----------+
|name1|1    |ab        |
|name2|1    |vf        |
|name2|2    |ee        |
|name2|3    |id        |
|name3|1    |bd        |
```

for every name there are multiple values which we need to bind together as shown below

Output dataframe :

```html
+-----+----------+
| name|value     |
+-----+----------+
|name1|[ab]      |
|name2|[vf,ee,id]|
|name3|[bd]      |
```

Thank you

Comment: `df.groupBy("name").agg(collect_list("value").alias("value"))`

Comment: @blackbishop thank you , solved my problem :)